# UIImageView: Fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to repeatedly display images, but I'm getting an out of range error.

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var im: UIImageView!
var images = ["page003.png","page004.png","page005.png","page006.png"]
var indice = 0
 @IBAction func n(sender: AnyObject) {
    indice++
    if indice == images.count
    {
    indice == 0
    }
    im.image = UIImage(named: (images[indice]))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `indice == 0` with `indice = 0`.